# SQL : find words that repeat in different rows of a table

Tags: mysql, sql, repeat

For example, I have that table

```
id      title
1       abcd apple 
2       adqsdd google
3       adzdaz android
4       gdfgdfg apple
5       yuiyu windows
```

so, we can see that the word **"apple"** is repeated in different rows.
How can I do a SQL Query, that will display who is the words repeat in different rows , so it will display me : **"apple"**

Comment: try a [regex](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) with count

Answer (score 0):

The only feasible way to do this is if you have a list of words.  If so:

```
select w.word, count(*)
from words w join
     t
     on concat(' ', t.title, ' ') like concat('% ', w.word, ' %')
group by w.word
having count(*) > 1;
```

EDIT:

If you don't have words, but you know that "title" has a fixed number of words, you can generate the available words.  For instance, if all titles have at most 4 words:

```
select w.word, count(*)
from (select substring_index(title, ' ', 1) as word union
      select substring_index(substring_index(title, ' ', 2), ' ', -1) union
      select substring_index(substring_index(title, ' ', 3), ' ', -1) union
      select substring_index(substring_index(title, ' ', 4), ' ', -1)

     ) w join
     t
     on concat(' ', t.title, ' ') like concat('% ', w.word, ' %')
group by w.word
having count(*) > 1;
```

You can obviously generalize this to longer titles.

Comment: wouldn't a regex with count not work and be faster along with less code?

Comment: unknown column title in field list

Answer (score 0):

Read up on `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`, those two will allow you select such conditions (using `HAVING COUNT(*)>1`, and similar).